# Need little help php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, sum

Here is the problem

```
$rd = do_mysql_query("SELECT sum(product_price * '{$count}') as letsee 
                      FROM prices 
                      WHERE product_id = '{$record['prodid']}' 
                      AND id='{$id_p}' 
                      ORDER BY product_id") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)){
echo "{$record['prodid']}:{$row['letsee']}<br />"; //id:count
}
```

its out for me

```
10:130
10:95
7:88
6:35
6:120
6:330
11:104
11:64
```

i need to Plus all counts by id

needed result

- 10:225
- 7:88
- 6:485
- 11:168

thanks

Comment: Use GROUP BY! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: IF I ADD GROUP BY product_id. it show me same results

Comment: try GROUP BY product_id,product_price

Comment: Have you looked in to `DISTINCT`? Not sure but it might work, let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with php:

```
foreach($records as $record){//First loop or something like it
    $rd = do_mysql_query("SELECT sum(product_price * '{$count}') as letsee FROM prices WHERE product_id = '{$record['prodid']}' AND id='{$id_p}' ORDER BY product_id") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)){
        $final_array[$record['prodid']]+=$row['letsee']; //id:count
    }
}//End of First loop or something like it

foreach($final_array as $key => $value){
     echo $key.':'.$value;
}
```

**Note: I think you should use php, because checking your code it seems, you have another loop to get `$record['prodid']` and `$count` which is causing the duplicates. This can't be solved with the query if you're sending the same product_id more than once.**

Comment: with try it out - Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in Z:\home\test2.ru\www\takeorders.php on line 90

Comment: forget the query, won't solve your issue, try the php

Comment: If i do like second (with php) its sow me [code]10:95
10:95
7:88
10:95
7:88
6:330
10:95
7:88
6:330
11:64[/code]

Comment: updated the code, you have to get the foreach out of the first loop. This way you create your array with total counts in it, then when the first loop is done, you do the foreach to print out results

Comment: get these: `foreach($final_array as $key => $value){
 echo $key.':'.$value;
}

$body .= "<p>";` out of this loop: `while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {` I think you should learn some DB `Normalization` before you continue coding in this way!

Comment: work thanks... i can't Normalization DB. Some one do this way. I just add more option (upgrate the site). Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rd = do_mysql_query("SELECT sum(product_price) as letsee FROM prices WHERE product_id = '{$record['prodid']}' AND id='{$id_p}' GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY product_id") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)){
echo "{$record['prodid']}:" . $row['letsee'] * $count ."<br />"; //id:count
}
```